# PHP - Remove Shortcodes and Content in between with Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
$text = My example text [shortcode_name]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.
```

And the following pattern:

```
$pattern= '/\[(\/?shortcode_name.*?(?=\]))\]/';
```

It gives me the following result:

```
preg_replace($pattern,'',$text);
My example text content of shortcode is cool.
```

This works like a charm to remove the shortcode.
What I'm looking for is to remove the shortcode and all content in between.

The result that I'm looking for is:

```
My example text is cool.
```

Comment: \[shortcode_name\].*?\[\/shortcode_name\]\s and use s modifier to match newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$pattern= '/\[(shortcode_name)\].*?\[\/\1\] ?/';
```

Explanation:

- match [
- followed by "shortcode_name" (captured within `(...)` for reuse in a later step, see below)
- followed by ]
- followed by anything, non-greedily (important!)
- followed by [/
- followed by what was matched in `(...)` earlier, in this example "shortcode_name"
- followed by ]
- followed by 1 or zero space

Answer (score 2):

This could maybe work as your regex:

```
/\[(\w+)\].*\[\/(\1)\]/
```

you find the first square bracket tag of any name, and grep the content in between, and then use lookback to find the closing square bracket. I only tested it with javascript, but it should work. Then you should use another regex to replace multiple whitespace for one whitespace :)

Answer (score 0):

You just accepted another answer while I was working on my solution, no problem :) but I still want to post my answer, as it can be more flexible if you have multiple shortcodes:

```
<?php

$shortCodes = array("shortcode_name", "shortcode_name2", "shortcode_name3");

$text = <<< EOF
My example text [shortcode_name]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.
another example text [shortcode_name2]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name2] is cool.
Yet another example  [shortcode_name3]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name3] is cool.
EOF;

foreach($shortCodes as $shortCode){
   $text = preg_replace("%\[$shortCode\].*?\[/$shortCode\]%i", '', $text);      
   $text = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/i', ' ', $text); //remove 2 or more spaces

}

echo $text;
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
My example text is cool.
another example text is cool.
Yet another example is cool.
```

---

**Demo:**
http://ideone.com/VhL5vm

Answer (score -1):

Try my version it will take care the newline as well.

```
$text = "My example text [shortcode_name]content of shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.";
$text = "My example text [shortcode_name]content of 
shortcode[/shortcode_name] is cool.";

$pattern= '/\[(shortcode_name)\](.|\s)*?\[\/\1\]/'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern,'' ,$text);
```

**Output**
My example text is cool.