# Strip shortcode, keep content in between

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, strip

The idea behind this question lies in getting excerpt of the posts created with avada but I can't strip the shortcodes from the post content to display the excerpt of the post.

Here is example of my post (using avada):

```
[fullwidth background_color="" background_image="" class="" id=""]
[one_full last="yes" spacing="yes" class="" id=""][fusion_text]
Content text ...   
[/fusion_text][/one_full][/fullwidth]`
```

The default `the_excerpt();` doesn't work because of shortcodes. `get_content()` returns the full post content including shortcodes. Using `strip_shortcodes()` also removes the content between the shortcodes.

So my plan would be to strip shortcodes using pattern? and trim the message to mimic the excerpt functionality. 
PS: This [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418336/php-remove-shortcodes-and-content-in-between-with-regex-pattern) doesn't work.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/stripping-shortcodes-keeping-the-content#post-2770209

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$excerpt = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $excerpt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth commenting that you can do this same thing using a text editor, for instance Notepad++ or EditPad Pro, using this Regex: `\[/?[^/\]]+/?\]`

That will match all shortcode, and you can then replace with nothing or a space, whatever.