# Need to remove legacy shortcodes w/ variable content from WordPress pages using MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shortcode, find-replace

I have many pages (posts) in a WP site with legacy short code that needs to be removed and cannot accomplish what I need using WordPress find/replace plug-ins - so I'm turning to MySQL queries.

The shortcodes to be removed all follow the same pattern: `"[nivo... (variable content) .../nivo]`

I need to remove the entire nivo shortcode and ONLY the nivo shortcode because other shortcodes exist on some pages.

I found something very close to what I think I need, and modified the obvious parameters for this particular application as follows...

```
UPDATE `post_content`
REPLACE(txt, SUBSTRING(txt, LOCATE('[nivo', txt), LENGTH(txt) - LOCATE('nivo]', REVERSE(txt)) - LOCATE('nivo]', txt) + 10), '')
WHERE  txt LIKE '%(%)%'
```

That `^^^` is accepted in the SQL query window (no stop signs) **but returns a #1064 error when executed.**

Ideally I would like to TEST this first on a specific post ID just to be sure it's really catching everything but I couldn't figure out how to write that into the query.

I know VERY little about MySQL (I'm a designer) but I have DB backups ready for rollback just in case.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you want to use a plugin or tool that allows you to use regex (regular expressions). I have used this Php tool, you just put it in your public_html and then access the path via a web browser: https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Just use a little regex in the Php tool or find a find and replace plugin that allows you to use regex. It would look something like this:

```
\[nivo.*?/nivo\]
```

`\` means escaping a character, since the bracket has a special meaning in regex.

`.` means any character

`*` means any number of characters

`?` means 0 or more

`.*?` together means anything or nothing

For reference (and probably a better answer):
[PHP - Remove Shortcodes and Content in between with Regex Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418336/php-remove-shortcodes-and-content-in-between-with-regex-pattern)

Comment: Came here to suggest this +1

Comment: Thank you both VERY much. I have a REGEX plug installed and will follow your instructions then post back

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I have the "Search Regex" plugin installed and tried your declaration exactly as shown.

There were no results returned.

Could the syntax be off slightly ???

Comment: Sorry - I see now that you said which tool to install / use. I'll try that...

Comment: Apparently, this is above my pay-grade, lol - I just couldn't make it work and had to revert to manually editing all the pages- but I will keep working on this as a personal project - in fact, I'm going to contact a developer friend about creating a WP plug-in specifically for this purpose - seems like it should be very "doable" via simple ASCII edits of on-page content using basic strings, variables and patterns - thank you again and best wishes in all you do

Comment: Ahh sorry that it didn't work out! Ya I didn't get to test that syntax but I think it would have been something very similar to that. You can normally do dry runs in interconnectit plugin where you could fine tune the regex without making any actual changes. Sorry that you had to go manual on it!